# Capture text log files to journald

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

Per [Journald man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html). This command can capture `stdout/stderr`, only, for running services. However, sometimes we would like to capture text logs into journald, For example, `nginx access.log`.

Is it possible to capture any text file using command such as `tail -f` into journald with `systemd tools`?

Comment: sure - you could write a service that did log-rotation and cat'd the files to the system log.  No one (realistically) does this since it's a lot of unnecessary clutter.

Comment: [similar answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/870925/nginx-not-logging-to-syslog), but I agree with @ThomasDickey. no-one does this.

Comment: You should be writing/using systemd unit files that capture these logs to journald if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The other way of phrasing the question, oft asked in the daemontools world over the past couple of decades, is _How do I persuade this program to just write its log to standard error instead of privately maintaining its own log file?_

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using the method discussed in this SF Q&A titled: [How can I send a message to the systemd journal from the command line?](https://serverfault.com/questions/573946/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-the-systemd-journal-from-the-command-line). This method uses the tool [`systemd-cat`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cat.html) which is similar in functionality to `logger`.

```
$ echo 'hello' | systemd-cat -p info
$ echo 'hello' | systemd-cat -p warning
$ echo 'hello' | systemd-cat -p emerg
```

Messages would show up like this in journald:

```
Feb 07 13:38:33 localhost.localdomain cat[15162]: hello
```

You can control the identifier details that show up in the logs like this:

```
$ echo 'hello' | systemd-cat -t someapp -p emerg
```

Resulting in this type of logging:

```
Feb 07 13:48:56 localhost.localdomain someapp[15278]: hello
```

**NOTE:** I'd still probably implement this using an actual systemd unit file designed to capture the logs of Nginx.